# Find the first string in a text file in whatever line I want using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to get the first string of the second line of a text file using a batch file, If possible get the first string of any line I want.

This is the text I want to parse:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                    CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
94c9dc4ba7c6        clearcmd6           "c:\\windows\\system..."   24 minutes ago      Exited (0) 23 minutes ago                       mycont
```

So I expect to get **94c9dc4ba7c6** inside a parameter.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Batch-file:**

```
@echo off
for /f "USEBACKQ tokens=1 skip=1 delims= " %%a in (text-file.txt) do (echo %%a)
```

**text-file.txt**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                    CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
94c9dc4ba7c6        clearcmd6           "c:\\windows\\system..."   24 minutes ago      Exited (0) 23 minutes ago                       mycont
```

**Output:**

> 94c9dc4ba7c6

Answer (score 0):

*You would need to bear in mind that the first string would be up to the first whitespace*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "file=text-file.txt"
Set "line=34"
Set/A "skip=line-1"
For /F "UseBackQ Skip=%skip%" %%A In ("%file%") Do Set "var=%%A"
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Echo(!var!
EndLocal
GoTo :EOF
```

You just input your required file name replacing `text-file.txt` on line number 2 and line number replacing `34` on line 3.